# Running Kivy App inside another python program

Tags: python, user-interface, asynchronous, io, kivy

I have a kivy app like this:

```
class SomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return something
```

When I try to import this and run  SomeApp.run() it blocks the process until I close the window, how can I have it run in the background and update when i call functions from my other .py file?

Answer (score 1):

Kivy `Apps` are event driven. In general, the "functions from my other .py file" should get called as a result of some event in the `App`. That event could be as simple as a `Clock` event. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.CyClockBase.schedule_once).